# How to Insert X Y and SRID 4326 to Geometry in Spring Boot and Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, jpa, geometry, gis

I use @query to Insert X Y to Geometry in Postgres. But it error.

```
@Modifying
@Query(value = " insert into mypoints (name,geom) values (:name,SRID=4326;POINT(:x :y))", nativeQuery = true)   
@Transactional
void addSPCTY(@Param("name") String ten,@Param("x") String x,@Param("y") String y);
```

Error in Java: `org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error near ;`

Hot to sert SRID in spring boot? Please hep me. Tks all

Comment: What is the type of geom column?

Comment: String in Java and Geometry in Postgres

Comment: I tried running query manually and it seems good, the exeption is from Postgres side. What I can think of it to try adding single quote as follows: @Query(value = " insert into mypoints (name,geom) values (':name','SRID=4326;POINT(:x :y)')", nativeQuery = true). I suggest this because when we try to run standalone insert query on postgres shell it requires values to be in single quotes. I believe same is the issue here

Comment: tks u. But it can't run . ERROR: parse error - invalid geometry
  Hint: "SRID=4326;POINT(:x" <-- parse error at position 18 within geometry

Answer (score 0):

I could insert record using following changes:

@Query(value = "insert into geometries (name,geom) values (:name, ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(:x, :y), 4326))", nativeQuery = true)

values for x and y has to be **passed as float** - if used String then it throws error. 
I hope it will help to resolve the issue.

Reference Doc: https://postgis.net/docs/ST_MakePoint.html